# Sources to learn HQL and Hibernate criteria query

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am completely new to hibernate and want to learn HQL ... I know basic MySql and want to relate Hibernate query with Mysql query Can some one please direct me to a good resource for learning HQL and criteria query... community doc are not explained very well...

Help is greatly appreciated.. As of home work I have already gone through following...

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations
http://sonivis.org/wiki/index.php/HowTo_use_Hibernate_Criteria_Queries
http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/criteriaqueyexample.shtml

and similar links but I want to learn it in depth...

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/index.html is the best place to start Hibernate. If you are looking for examples there are many, including one post by me [here](http://jyops.blogspot.com/2011/03/hibernate-mapping-example.html).

Let me also share some links that helped me.

1. http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/
2. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/spring-mvc3-hibernate-crud-sample.html
3. http://krams915.blogspot.com/search/label/Hibernate

Comment: problum with community doc is...it is not giving me sql equivalent of a query

Comment: If the table name is TABLE_1 and column name is COL_1, COL_2 and your sql is <i>select COL_1,COL_2 from TABLE_1</i> the corresponding hql will be <i>select prop2,prop2 from TableBean</i> where TableBean is your POJO representing the TABLE_1 and prop1 and prop2 are the attributes in the class.  Do go through some examples before u catch up with the documentation. Hope you will have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Example sites and blog posts will answer point questions, but if you really want a broad overview, learning in depth with full examples, you might want to consider buying a book.  [Hibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/bauer/) is a standard reference.